# Is there a method for importing a R formula into TMB cpp

Tags: r, tmb

I would like to import into TMB a user formula that is used as the prediction equation in a likelihood function.
Is there any way of doing this?  Could you point me to a relevant example?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

For example in the simple linear regression code below, a+b*x is the predictor equation

```
#include <TMB.hpp>
template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
DATA_VECTOR(Y);
DATA_VECTOR(x);
PARAMETER(a);
PARAMETER(b);
PARAMETER(logSigma);
ADREPORT(exp(2*logSigma));
Type nll = -sum(dnorm(Y, a+b*x, exp(logSigma), true));
return nll;
}
```

I would like to an user-specified formula to be used in place of a+b*x.

Comment: Meaning the user specifies it in R? As a formula (with `~`), as a string ... ?  I think you'd have to do this by text processing.

Comment: The usual approach is to pass the design matrix, which can be created in R from a model formula. The design matrix is then matrix multiplied with your coefficient vector in the C or C++ code. I strongly suggest you follow that approach.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the formula will always be a linear function (of the predictors)?

Comment: It sounds like you want the second argument of `dnorm` to be determined at run time rather than at compile time, from an arbitrary specified formula?  I suspect that that won't be possible without evaluating R code.  You can define a finite number of options with a `switch` statement (for example), but if the formula is arbitrary, then you'll likely have to generate and compile the template on the fly.

Comment: The user will specify the formula in R (e.g., sl~Linf*(1-exp(-K*(age-t0))), and I would like to pass that formula into a TMB cpp where the parameters will be solved by different likelihoods (selected by user also).  The formulae will be non-linear growth models.